# Can't set layout gravity for RelativeLayout programmatically

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

**Try #1**: I am trying to set layout gravity for `RelativeLayout` programmatically.

```
    FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    frameLayout.setLayoutParams(frameLayoutParams);
    setViewPaddingInDp(frameLayout, 16, 16, 16, 16);

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    relativeLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams);
    frameLayout.addView(relativeLayout);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    setViewWidthAndHeight(imageView, 128, 192);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.maxwell);
    relativeLayout.addView(imageView);

    setContentView(frameLayout);
```

This is what I am getting as result:

[image]

**Try #2**: I have tried set `CENTER_IN_PARENT` programmatically, but no result

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams);
        frameLayout.addView(relativeLayout);
```

**Try #3**: Also tried to set `CENTER_HORIZONTAL`, but no effect:

```
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    // relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    // relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams);
    frameLayout.addView(relativeLayout);
```

How to set layout gravity `CENTER` for `RelativeLayout`? I need to set gravity for `RelativeLayout` without changing `FrameLayout` or `ImageView` layout params.

Comment: change `WRAP_CONTENT` to `MATCH_PARENT` , look at the updated answer

Comment: changed to MATCH_PARENT, anyways does not center

Comment: share the code of this method setViewPaddingInDp

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix, just verified myself. Working as required. The important part we were missing is `imageViewParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);`

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
frameLayout.setLayoutParams(frameLayoutParams);
//setViewPaddingInDp(frameLayout, 16, 16, 16, 16);

RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
relativeLayoutParams.addRule(CENTER_IN_PARENT, TRUE);
relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams);

frameLayout.addView(relativeLayout);

ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
// params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
// params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
// setViewWidthAndHeight(imageView, 128, 192); // if you are using this method, then set the layout param accordingly
// imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.maxwell);

relativeLayout.addView(imageView);

setContentView(frameLayout);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, unfortunately it did not help :(

Comment: It should work, just updated.. there were typo mistake

Comment: @JoeRakhimov Updated the answer, verified myself this time. Working as requested. Review the updated answer

Comment: thank you again for your answer, but it is not working :(

Comment: If you copy paste the answer in your code it should simply work. If the solution work for you then revisit your methods `setViewPaddingInDP` and `setViewWidthAndHeight` and figure out if something going wrong. Better if you share those methods too.

Answer (score 0):

Set `MATCH_PARENT` instead of `WRAP_CONTENT` to RelativeLayout like

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams = new 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

And set a `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` to your ImageView

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, 
RelativeLayout.TRUE);
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: @AnisuzzamanBabla Sorry I have updated your answer by mistake, kindly ignore